# how to implement AsyncLoader in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, loader

I want to show Loader in Android. I am having loader which run for specific time time as described here .

```
private void showLoader(String message){
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(TabletFighters.this,                    message,"Loading.." , true);
    dialog.show();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
        }   
    }, 3000);   
}`
```

But the Problem is I am showing this loader during Bluetooth connection(again `Thread`) which hide the loader.How could I make AsyLoader in Android , so that Loader can show during Bluetooth Conection(showing message `connecting to device`).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class showdialogexample extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {  

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
                    // do your process here 
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
                    dialog.show();      
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
```